# Angular Jasmine 2.0 test familiarity, Pending() fails to recon in body and it('errors with no function');

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Moving to Jasmine 2.x and I was testing pending specs.  I am getting failures trying to use pending() in a spec body and I find that it('without a function") is throwing an

Error: undefined is not a function.

xit works fine

When all specs are marked as xit() I don't get a count on pending specs

```
    0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures
```

code

```
    describe("Pending specs", function() {

    //Any spec declared with xit is marked as pending.

      xit("can be declared 'xit'", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
      });

    //Any spec declared without a function body will also be marked pending in results.

      it("can be declared with 'it' but without a function");

    //And if you call the function pending anywhere in the spec body, no matter the expectations, the spec will be marked pending.

      it("can be declared by calling 'pending' in the spec body", function() {
        expect(true).toBe(false);
        pending();
      });
    });
```

ERROR MSG
Failure: it("can be declared with 'it' but without a function");

```
      1) Pending specs encountered a declaration exception
       Message:
         Error: undefined is not a function
       Stacktrace:
         Error: undefined is not a function
```

Failure: pending()

commenting out the bad spec

the pending() does not seem to prevent 
the last spec from executing and I get a 
Reference Error: pending is not defined

```
     Pending specs can be declared by calling 'pending' in the spec body
       Message:
         ReferenceError: pending is not defined
       Stacktrace:
         ReferenceError: pending is not defined
```